# Почему GET не работает одновременно с POST?

Tags: php, symfony

Вот контроллер:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AppsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/apps", name="apps")
     */
    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/apps", name="apps")
     */
    public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
    }
}
```

Пока не было `postAction` все работало нормально, но когда я его добавил стал работать только `postAction`, а на `listAction` ругается "No route found for "GET /apps": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)". В чем дело? Мне надо чтобы они были по одному пути, но с разными методами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get`, `Post` и прочие являются наследниками `Route`.
Указывать `"name"` для `@Route` необязательно, он генерируется автоматически.

В аннотации ошибка, достаточно удалить `name` или задать его уникальные значения для методов - всё заработает. [Здесь](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/7-manual-route-definition.html#method-name-prefix) описано как это устроено.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в symfony устроены маршруты, но попробую на примере laravel Объяснить.

В нём создаются маршруты по типу:

```
Route::get('/apps', 'AppsController@listAction');
Route::post('/apps', 'AppsController@postAction');
```

Тем самым когда Вы обращаетесь по get запросу вызывается первый метод, а по post второй! по uri /apps

Указывая `@Rest\Post("/apps", name="apps")` у вас в комментариях, вы определяете тип обращения! Ошибка которая у Вас возникла сообщает о том что:

```
Route::get(/apps, 'AppsController@listAction'); -- Вы не создали данный маршрут
Route::post(/apps, 'AppsController@postAction'); -- а этот создали
```

Решение. В файле указания маршрутов необходимо создать маршрут для GET

Comment: В Симфони маршруты определяются аннотациями. Это не просто комментарий - он значащий. Отдельные файлы машрутов бывают, но я их не использую - так удобнее

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Значит Вы указываете для двух маршрутов одинаковое имя "apps", а оно должно быть разное. И данная аннотация переопределяет маршрут!

Comment: А вот сейчас попал. Действительно - когда я убрал вообще параметр `name` у обоих методов все заработало как надо. Это так в примере просто было. Не знаю даже зачем он. Спасибо.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК Рад помочь!

Comment: вот за что минусанули человека? Проблему же решил, от меня `+`

Comment: @Gedweb сам ответ неверный. Он решил ее в комментариях. Верный коммент плюсанул. Если обновит ответ поставлю плюс и ему :)

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК согласен, ответ нужно актуализировать